# Configuring VNC session for admin rights on ubuntu

Tags: permissions, configuration, tightvncserver, vncviewer

I configured VNC on Ubuntu headless, using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04).

I don't have any administrative access to set up anything and I need to know what I need to do to raise the level permission on the file system. What should I do?